# Python Flask calling threaded function

Tags: python, jquery, flask

I have a pretty simple flask/jquery application I put together.  Basically I am loading configs on several network routers using the netmiko library.  I pass some json data to flask via a jquery post.  This tells the backend flask application which network configs I want to load on the devices.  This data gets passed on to a function that then does the work of copying configs to devices.  When I pass this data to the function and don't used threading(load each network device sequentially), everything works fine.  When I implemented threading(loading the configs on all devices concurrently) I am having issues.  The problem is the 200 response code is never received when doing the threading method.  It seems like the function that loads the devices never ends(but it does) so the flask view never hits the render template.  I confirmed the 200 is never received via wireshark capture.  When I run the threaded application outside of flask(just via cli) it does return the cli, so it looks like it's not getting hung.  Not sure how to debug or see whey the render template is never firing.  The flask view is below.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
@app.route("/labs", methods=["GET","POST"])
def labs():
if request.method == "POST":
        lab = request.form['lab']
        for key,value in status.items():
            print(key,"--",value)
        loadlab(lab)
        return render_template("labs.html", content=status, progbar=progressbar)
    else:
        return render_template("labs.html", content=status, progbar=progressbar)
```

Comment: I was able to figure out what I think is going on here.  I wrote a simple flask view to poll the number of threads. The threads never get to zero, so the thread call never ends, so flask never returns a 200.  It seems like flask is using the same pool of threads that my script is using, and it never gets to 0 threads.  Researching some different ways to handle the threads to prevent this from happening.